# Conductive Rod in a Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, induction, electromagnetic-induction

I have a question about induction.

Imagine a conductive object being moved in a magnetic field. What forces will it experience and how does the induced current in the object affect the motion, will the induced current lead to a magnetic force itself? If so, in what direction?

This kind of scenario:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let there be an uniform magnetic field $\mathbf B$ & through it a conductive bar is moving with velocity $\mathbf v.$ Let the observer be viewing the moving bar where the soure of the magnetic field is at rest.

Since, the bar is moving with velocity $\mathbf v,$ the charges in the bar are also moving with velocity $\mathbf v$ along with their random velocity which, *in average*, is zero .

Each charge would then get forced by the magnetic field which is expressed by this relation $$\mathbf F = q\;\mathbf v\times \mathbf B\;.$$

These charges would then feel a side force which would make them drift in one direction.

Now, since these charges are moving from one side to the other, the bar is overall getting positively & negatively charged at either ends giving rise to an electric field.

At steady-state, electric field nullifies the Lorentz force, which is given as $$\mathbf E= -\mathbf v\times \mathbf B \;.$$  As the Lorentz force is acting sideways, it wouldn't affect the motion of the bar.

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination. However, what would happen if the bar is in a closed circuit and is still moving. This would result in a current moving in the circuit. Let's say there is a resistance R in the circuit as well. What would happen with the motion and the magnetic fields then? :)

Comment: You mean to say instead of the bar, there is a closed circuit moving through the field?

Comment: Nah, rater a bar moving upon two static, parallell conductive wires that are connected to each other. Imagine the bar gliding on the two wires. Do you understand what I mean? The bar is moving, but the other parts aren't.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not getting what you're saying. However, you can edit your post to include this query in your question in a more elaborate way so that others can also gaze at your problem & may answer to the query .

Comment: Then there would be an induced current through the bar & the other wires. Since, the loop area is decreasing, the flux is also changing which means there the induced current tends to nullify the flux change; that's Lenz's law. The bar would feel force from the magnetic field then.

Comment: And that force would be directed opposite the movement (v) right with a strength of F = magnetic field * current * length of the bar. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right.